# How to disable as-you-type JBT Validator

Tags: jboss, jboss-developer-studio

I am working in JBoss Developer Stutio, and i often see the "As-you-type JBT validor" message, and when it occurs, I can do nothing, since it consumes lots of resources. In Preferences->validation->JSF view validator, I can't disable it specifically, since there is only a choice of "Enable all" or "Disable all" options.

How to get rid of this headache?

Answer (score 11):

If you see it when editing xhtml/html/jsp or xmls files then it's JBoss Tools As-you-type validation. You can disable it in Preferences->JBoss Tools->Web->JSF->Validation

There is no specific preference for As-you-type validation, so, the only way to disable it is to disable all JBoss JSF validation. You also can do it in project properties for the project only.

But if you see it when editing Java files then it's CDI validation. You can disable it in JBoss Tools->CDI->Validation.